# Can someone please explain why my code is not executing without error? I've done research but i can't see where i made a mistake

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Trying to create roles in SQL and assign them permissions. After i creating the roles i want to create new users to assign to role

```
Create Role Sales_Person
    Grant Insert on Northwind.dbo(Customers, Orders, OrderDetails) 
    To Sales_Person
    Grant Select, Update on Northwind.dbo.Customers(CompanyName, ContactName, ContactTitle, Address, City, Region, PostalCode, Country, Phone, Fax)
    To Sales_Person
Create Role Sale_Manager
    Grant Insert, Delete on Northwind.dbo(Customers, Orders, OrderDetails)
    To Sale_Manager
    Grant Select, Update on Northwind.dbo.Customers(CompanyName, ContactName, ContactTitle, Address, City, Region, PostalCode, Country, Phone, Fax)
    To Sale_Manager
Create Role HR_Person
    Grant Insert on Northwind.dbo.Employees
    To HR_Person
    Grant Select, Update on Northwind.dbo.Employees(LastName, FirstName, Title, TitleOfCourtesy, BirthDate, HireDate, Address, City, Region, PostalCode, HomePhone, Country, Extension, Notes, ReportTo)
    To HR_Person
Create Role HR_Manager
    Grant Insert, Delete on Northwind.dbo.Employees
    To HR_Manager
    Grant Select, Update on Northwind.dbo.Employees(LastName, FirstName, Title, TitleOfCourtesy, BirthDate, HireDate, Address, City, Region, PostalCode, HomePhone, Country, Extension, Notes, ReportTo)
    To HR_Manager
Create User Jane1 Without Login
    Grant Sales_Person to Jane1
Create User Joan1 Without Login
    Grant Sale_Manager to Joan1
Create User Joe1 Without Login
    Grant HR_Person to Joe1
Create User James1 Without Login
```

> Error message saying "Msg 1020, Level 15, State 1, Line 0
>   Sub-entity lists (such as column or security expressions) cannot be specified for entity-level permissions."

Comment: What happens if you remove the column names as the error implies?

Comment: Start by ending the statements with semicolons.

Comment: which line is giving the error message ?

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking out the tables, it looks to be reading them as columns for some of the insert and delete parts. Permissions for insert and delete must be done at table level, not column.

```
Create Role Sales_Person
    Grant Insert on Northwind.dbo.Customers 
    To Sales_Person
    Grant Insert on Northwind.dbo.Orders
    To Sales_Person
    Grant Insert on Northwind.dbo.OrderDetails
    To Sales_Person
    Grant Select, Update on Northwind.dbo.Customers(CompanyName, ContactName, ContactTitle, Address, City, Region, PostalCode, Country, Phone, Fax)
    To Sales_Person
Create Role Sale_Manager
    Grant Insert, Delete on Northwind.dbo.Customers
    To Sale_Manager
    Grant Insert, Delete on Northwind.dbo.Orders
    To Sale_Manager
    Grant Insert, Delete on Northwind.dbo.OrderDetails
    To Sale_Manager
    Grant Select, Update on Northwind.dbo.Customers(CompanyName, ContactName, ContactTitle, Address, City, Region, PostalCode, Country, Phone, Fax)
    To Sale_Manager
Create Role HR_Person
    Grant Insert on Northwind.dbo.Employees
    To HR_Person
    Grant Select, Update on Northwind.dbo.Employees(LastName, FirstName, Title, TitleOfCourtesy, BirthDate, HireDate, Address, City, Region, PostalCode, HomePhone, Country, Extension, Notes, ReportTo)
    To HR_Person
Create Role HR_Manager
    Grant Insert, Delete on Northwind.dbo.Employees
    To HR_Manager
    Grant Select, Update on Northwind.dbo.Employees(LastName, FirstName, Title, TitleOfCourtesy, BirthDate, HireDate, Address, City, Region, PostalCode, HomePhone, Country, Extension, Notes, ReportTo)
    To HR_Manager
Create User Jane1 Without Login
    Grant Sales_Person to Jane1
Create User Joan1 Without Login
    Grant Sale_Manager to Joan1
Create User Joe1 Without Login
    Grant HR_Person to Joe1
Create User James1 Without Login
```